# Why is God considered by many to be a male?

Tags: nature-of-god, gender

I am not a Christian, but I believe in many of the biblical stories and the message that they provide for the world to be a better place. I think the Bible could be more accepted and it’s strong ethical messages become regarded and understood better, if people discussing the Bible would use more inclusive language.

I just wanted to see you alls thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

Because Christians believe God inspired the scriptures, and in the scriptures he predominantly uses masculine pronouns and masculine imagery to talk about himself. There are different views of inspiration, but in all the major branches of Christianity I think it would be accurate to say that most Christians believe that God has so worked inspiration that while the human authors did express their individual voices, what they wrote is exactly what God wanted to be written. While there are many cultural accommodations in scripture, the masculinity of God is not one, for it would have been very difficult easy to write about God as female or as both or as neither, as the pagan gods around them were of all genders.

I think there's a little bit of irony in this age of accepting and using people's preferred pronouns that some people don't want to use God's preferred pronouns ;). I think that ultimately comes from people not accepting that the scriptures are inspired by God.

Comment: I can not speak onto what was written in the Bible, as I have not read it. But what if the people who wrote it just used the masculine pronoun because that was thought to be normal at the time.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that if anything, it is disrespectful to God to consider God to be confined to a gender. To me it seems if we are talking about the all powerful creator God, we would think past gender. Why would God be either male or female, and if we use the masculine pronoun, doesn’t that seem like it would be quite exclusive to all men in this world. Which to me seems a little backwards considering God teaches to accept and love all people, not just man.

Comment: As I said, this problem can only be a problem if God is not the author of scripture. Your question would be fair if we thought the Bible was purely a human creation, but most Christians would strongly reject that. God does indeed teach us to love both genders (and even those who don't identify as either) just as he loves all. That doesn't mean he can't identify as male or at least want us to think of him as male and address him as male.

Answer (score 4):

In many languages (including Hebrew) most nouns have a strong gender component—but the gender assignment is grammatical and does not necessarily indicate the physical gender of the object. In Spanish, a guitar (la guitarra) is feminine, and a car (el coche) is masculine. This has nothing to do with literal gender. For example, the Spanish word masculinidad, which means “masculinity,” is a feminine noun! Therefore, when translating from Hebrew into English, we must distinguish grammatical gender from our notions of sexual gender.

Another example is the English wisdom is grammatically neuter, but not so in Hebrew. The Hebrew word is chokmoth, and it is grammatically feminine. In Hebrew, it would have been natural to speak of wisdom as a “she.” That is why the book of Proverbs personifies wisdom as a woman.

With regards to God, the Bible informs us that God is neither male nor female:

> “God is spirit, and his worshipers must worship in spirit and in truth” (John 4:24).

Since God is a spiritual being, He does not possess physical human characteristics. However, sometimes figurative language used in Scripture assigns human characteristics to God in order to make it possible for man to understand God. This assignment of human characteristics to describe God is called “anthropomorphism.”

> “Anthropomorphism is the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities. It is considered to be an innate tendency of human psychology.”  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism

Anthropomorphism is simply a means for God (a spiritual being) to communicate truth about His nature to humanity, physical beings. Since humanity is physical, we are limited in our understanding of those things beyond the physical realm; therefore, anthropomorphism in Scripture helps us to understand who God is.

Answer (score 0):

To be as brief as a breeze, The Bible speaks of God being a HE/HIM and is spoken of as a person, despite him being unseen and a Spirit, lastly, he is known as the incorruptible Father and when he speaks of something and or himself, it should be very clear.

Comment: Is it possible however, that the people and realistically the men who wrote the Bible, could they have made a mistake? God accepts that people make mistakes, and maybe those people made mistakes as well, and we are excluding women from the language of the Bible by what could be a mistake.

Comment: One thing for certain, women are not excluded by no means for both men and women, even if the church, both have different roles, for we have examples found in the Bible itself, this goes for women in the days the church didn't exist yet. That being said, it isn't mistake when the Bible itself even identifies God as the Father, thus we know God is a He/Him, even when spoken of. But yes, later down the road, there have been those who did make some mistakes, for a passage and or verse does not match the Strong's of Hebrew/Greek, which is in connection with Manuscript evidence.